# Совмещение PHP и JS

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Необходимо совместить php и js код. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы запросы в БД отправлялись только после возникновения события копирования информации с span тега. Нижеследующий код не работает, запросы в БД отправляются сразу при загрузке страницы. Что можно сделать для решения проблемы?

```
<script>
    let questions_fields = document.querySelectorAll(".question_text span");
    let number_of_try_copy = 0;
    questions_fields.forEach(function(questions_field) {
        questions_field.addEventListener("copy", function (event){
            number_of_try_copy++;
            let violation_text = "Не пытайтесь скопировать информацию!"; //Обнаружено " + number_of_try_copy + " попыток копирования.";
            event.preventDefault();
            // Сохранение в БД
            <?php
                   $query_violations = "SELECT * FROM violation WHERE stud_id = '$s' AND g_id = '$g_id'";
                   $result_violations = mysqli_query($link, $query_violations) or die(mysqli_error($link));
                   $result_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_violations);
                   if(mysqli_num_rows($result_violations)>0){
                       $query_violation_info = "UPDATE violation SET copy = copy + 1 WHERE stud_id = '$s' AND g_id = '$g_id'";
                   }else{
                       $query_violation_info = "INSERT INTO violation (stud_id, g_id, type, copy) VALUES ('$s', '$g_id', '0', 1)";
                   }
                   mysqli_query($link, $query_violation_info) or die(mysqli_error($link));
            ?>
            modal_show(violation_text);
        });
    });
    <script>
```

Comment: Ваша логика - как только на странице попытались что-то скопировать, сработала моя `JS`-функция которая выполнила ....`PHP`-код! Вас ничего не смущает? При загрузке страницы, `php`-парсер ищет внутри страницы `php`-код и выполняет его! Для достижения Вашей цели Вам необходимо в момент срабатывания `JS`-функции сделать `AJAX`-запрос к серверу, где Ваш `php`-скрипт уже и сделает сохранение в БД.

Comment: @user413219 Благодарю за подробное объяснение

Comment: Нестареющая классика http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke#js